# R paste0 2 columns if not NA

Tags: r

I would like to `paste0` two columns if the element in one column is not `NA`.If one  element 
 of one columns is `NA` then keep the element of the other column only.

```
structure(list(col1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), 
          class = "factor"), col2 = c(1, NA, 3)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), 
          class =   "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -3L))

#   col1 col2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B   NA
# 3    C    3

structure(list(col1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"),
          class = "factor"),col2 = c(1, NA, 3), col3 = c("A|1", "B", "C|3")),
         .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA,-3L),
          class = "data.frame")

#  col1 col2 col3
#1    A    1  A|1
#2    B   NA    B
#3    C    3  C|3
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? This should be easy using `ifelse`.

Comment: you say you want to use `paste0`, but your example looks like the result of `paste` ...

Comment: @BenBolker that's was a typo of mine. I meant past0. will correct it. Is there a way to perform this task without ifelse?

Comment: probably, but can you explain why you want to avoid `ifelse`? it seems to be the simplest and easiest way to do this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roland says, this is easy using `ifelse` (just translate the mental logic into a series of nested `ifelse` statements):

```
x <- transform(x,col3=ifelse(is.na(col1),as.character(col2),
                     ifelse(is.na(col2),as.character(col1),
                          paste0(col1,"|",col2))))
```

*update*: need `as.character` in some cases.

Comment: I tried your method and got a 2 instead of the B in the column 3. That was part of the reason why i wanted to find another way.

Answer (score 3):

you can also do it with regular expressions:

```
df$col3 <- sub("NA\\||\\|NA", "", with(df, paste0(col1, "|", col2)))
```

That is, paste them in regular way and then replace any "NA|" or "|NA" with "". Note that `|` needs to be "double escaped" because it means "OR" in regexps, that's why the strange pattern `NA\\||\\|NA` means actually "NA|" OR "|NA".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> df$col1 = as.character(df$col1)
> df$col3 = with(df, ifelse(is.na(col1),col2, ifelse(is.na(col2), col1, paste0(col1,'|',col2))))
> df
  col1 col2 col3
1    A    1  A|1
2    B   NA    B
3    C    3  C|3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
  library(stringr)
  df$col3 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) 
              paste(str_trim(x[!is.na(x)]), collapse="|"))
  df
  #  col1 col2 col3
  #1    A    1  A|1
  #2    B   NA    B
  #3    C    3  C|3
```